# Sort depending on variable in Scala

Tags: list, scala, sorting

Is there any way in Scala to sort a list of objects by a specific field using a variable to set the order (ASC or DESC)?

I know with sortWith you can do something like

```
myList.sortWith((x, y) => x < y)
```

or

```
myList.sortWith((x, y) => x > y)
```

to sort ascending or descending, but I want to use a variable.

So, I tried something like this:

```
case class Person(firstName: String, LastName: String, age: Int)

private def sortDocuments(sortField: String, sortDirection: String, people: List[Person]): List[Person] = {
  sortField match {
    case "age" => people.sortBy(if (sortDirection == "desc") -_.age else _.age)
    case "firstName" => people.sortWith { sortString(a.firstName, b.firstName, sortDirection) }
    case "lastName" => people.sortWith { sortString(a.firstName, b.lastName, sortDirection) }
  }
}

private def sortString(fieldA: String = null, fieldB: String = null, direction: String = "asc") = {
  val fieldAVaild = Option(fieldA).getOrElse("")
  val fieldBVaild = Option(fieldB).getOrElse("")
  if (direction == "desc") fieldBVaild > fieldAVaild else fieldAVaild < fieldBVaild
}
```

But sortWith only receives a function with two parameters, so I get an error when I add the third parameter (sortDirection).

Comment: You might want to look into sortBy, which should be sufficient for your use case and simpler to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `(a, b) => expr` part of the first/last name cases

```
case "firstName" => people.sortWith {(a, b) => sortString(a.firstName, b.firstName, sortDirection) }
```